# Jquery + Select + Hide Div Based on Selected index value

Tags: jquery, select, hide, html-select

I'm an intermediate designer/developer stuck on a simple problem which I can't figure out.

Maybe it's just me working for almost 8 hours straight now, but if anyone can help I would appreciate it ever so much.

In short, I have 3 dropdowns:

1. no of children.
2. baby seats.
3. booster seats.

Now by default, only the first dropdown shows (no of children). The other two are hidden by default in css. What I'm trying to do here is, IF the value of (no of children) dropdown is NOT zero then show the other two dropdowns that are encapsulated in DIVs by jquery.

This is my XHTML code thus far, no error, but nothing happens either:

```
    <div class="title">No of Children:</div>
    <div class="info">
      <select name="children" id="no_of_children">
        <option value="0" selected>0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="title" id="baby">Baby Seats?:</div>
    <div class="info">
      <select name="babyseats" id="baby_seats">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="title" id="booster">Booster seats?:</div>
    <div class="info">
      <select name="boosterseats" id="booster_seats">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

This is my jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
      $('#no_of_children').bind('change', function(event) {

      var x = $('#no_of_children').val();         
 if( x == "0" ) {             
    $('#booster').hide();
    $('#baby').hide();      
 }         
      });
    </script>
```

Nothing happens. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#booster` and `#baby` elements you are hiding only contain the title.

Try revising your HTML like so. They JavaScript should work as is.

```
<div id="baby">
  <div class="title">Baby Seats?:</div>
  <div class="info">
    <select name="babyseats" id="baby_seats">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="booster">
  <div class="title">Booster seats?:</div>
  <div class="info">
    <select name="boosterseats" id="booster_seats">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently Working on a fiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/G7wdT/1

Would be nice to encapsulate the entire select in a common Div.

You need to Show the divs when the value is not 0, in an Else statement of your current JS.

Here is the code:

```
 <div class="title">No of Children:</div>
<div class="info">
  <select name="children" id="no_of_children">
    <option value="0" selected>0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="title" id="baby">Baby Seats?:
    <div class="info">
      <select name="babyseats" id="baby_seats">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="title" id="booster">Booster seats?:
   <div class="info">
      <select name="boosterseats" id="booster_seats">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the js

```
$('#no_of_children').bind('change', function(event) {

var x = $('#no_of_children').val();

if (x == "0") {
    $('#booster').hide();
    $('#baby').hide();
}else{
    $('#booster').show();
    $('#baby').show();
}
```

});​

Comment: Thank you for ultra fast responses, damn you guys are quick!! If anyone needs freelance work, im overloaded!! .. I got it to work without any change, only prob was i had my js in the wrong place.. Also i had put the div element wrong in the code i wrote here.. it was as @zenbait said below

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple typo in selector for `$('#baby')`...missing closing quote

Code works otherwise, although not sure it is effect you want

http://jsfiddle.net/YbKSk/1/

Comment: Thank you for you quick response, got it to work liek a charm. its just long hours make fruitless mistakes. :) thanks very much though

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#no_of_children').bind('change', function (event) {

            var x = $('#no_of_children').val();
            if (x == "0") {
                $('#booster').hide();
                $('#baby').hide();
            } else {
                $('#booster').show();
                $('#baby').show();
            }
        });
    });


<div class="title">
    No of Children:</div>
<div class="info">
    <select name="children" id="no_of_children">
        <option value="0" selected>0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="title" id="baby" style="display: none;">
    Baby Seats?:
    <div class="info">
        <select name="babyseats" id="baby_seats">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="title" id="booster" style="display: none;">
    Booster seats?:
    <div class="info">
        <select name="boosterseats" id="booster_seats">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your jQuery is contained inside of

```
$(function () {

    //YOUR CODE HERE
});
```

Running your code as is will not initialize the change event

Comment: And hide the two selects from the start as well since 0 is selected by default

Comment: Its working now, yes i had it in there, just in wrong place. :) cheers